# no result react-native-searchable-dropdown

Tags: react-native, searchable-dropdown

I using react-native-searchable-dropdown library , but if user write string with its not in item array I receive white screen.
How I can add no result text (or its best option button who create missing option)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is work , just i need to add some details , its need to be change the same Searchable dropdown file:

```
 const oldSupport = [
        { key: 'keyboardShouldPersistTaps', val: 'always' }, 
        { key: 'nestedScrollEnabled', val : false },
        { key: 'style', val : { ...this.props.itemsContainerStyle } },
        { key: 'data', val : this.state.listItems },
        { key: 'keyExtractor', val : (item, index) => index.toString() },
        { key: 'renderItem', val : ({ item, index }) => this.renderItems(item, index) },
        { key: 'ListEmptyComponent', val : () =>this.emptyComponent()}
    
I added : 
        { key: 'ListEmptyComponent', val : () =>this.emptyComponent()}
```

after that i just add

```
emptyComponent = () => {
    return(
      <View>
       <Text>Search result not found</Text>
       <Button title='Do Something'/>
    </View>
    );
  };
```

and in function

> emptyComponent

you can do whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flatlist to list all your data. There is a prop called ListEmptyComponent

```
import React from 'react', 
import {FlatList, Button, Text} from 'react-native',


const emptyComponent = () => {
  return(
     <Text>Search result not found</Text>
     <Button title='Do Something'/>
  )
};

<FlatList
  istEmptyComponent={emptyComponent}
 />
```

This will display if the search results where not found.